# How to automatically bundle wasm used by a dependency?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webassembly, emscripten

My website uses a package.
This package is a Typescript port of a low level networking library written in C. The porting was done with emscripten, which gives us a `networking.wasm` and `networking.js` files. We added some manual TS code to use the package in a mode TS-idiomatic way.

I want my react website to depend on that package, but I don't want to have to **manually copy the `networking.wasm` file into my `public/static/js` directory** for the underlying 'networking' package to work. I want the 'networking' package to work out of the box with a simple `npm install`.

How can I make the 'networking' package my site depends on tell webpack to add the `networking.wasm` file where it needs to be to be GET correctly ?
If this is not possible, what would be the cleanest solution to expose the .wasm file for the user of the package to copy in the right place to get GET ?

Comment: I wonder if [this example by surma would be helpful to you](https://gist.github.com/surma/b2705b6cca29357ebea1c9e6e15684cc). You could also try using [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For emscripten user, you can build with the flag

```
-s SINGLE_FILE=1
```

so the entire wasm binary content gets written in the generated .js file as a literal string. Therefore all you need is the generated javascript file, no need to worry about the webassembly file.